# How to make HStack with .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) fill equally?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to make a HStack for custom tabbar. I need my images inside HStack to be filling equally. Current progress is as following. Any idea? I'm new to SwiftUI.

```
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Main View")
            Spacer()
            MainTabBar()
                .background(Color.primaryBackground)
        }
    }
}

struct MainTabBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            Image.chatTabBarItem
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(4)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    
                }
            Image.groupTabBarItem
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(4)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    
                }
            Image.circleTabBarItem
                .renderingMode(.template)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 26, height: 26)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding(4)
                .clipShape(Circle())
                .onTapGesture {
                    
                }
        }
        .frame(height: 60)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(Color.green)
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accepted answer uses `Spacer`. This will share up the spare space equally between the `Spacer`. This is fine if you want equal spacing *between* the items and works well when the items themselves are equal width.

However, if the items do not all have the same width, then this might not be what you want. For example, if the third item in your group was smaller in width than the others then the middle item would not be centered.

An alternative approach is to apply `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity)` to the items. This will give each of the items an equal amount of space. To constrain the overall width of the group, just put a fixed width on the container that encloses them.

Like this:

```swift
HStack {
  Image(...)
     .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
  Image(...)
     .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
  Image(...)
     .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
}
.frame(width: 300)
```

With this approach, it doesn't matter if the items are different sizes, the middle one will always be centered.

Comment: You're totally correct. Your approach is more suitable way. Because later I put background color to my images (using ZStack) and animated it. Images move with animation with Spacer approach. But they still remain perfectly with your approach.

Comment: I would say, there will be times when you want to use ```Spacer``` and other times when you want to use ```maxWidth```. They are both valid solutions. But I'm pleased if you've found a solution that's suitable.